# three.js EdgesHelper showing certain diagonal lines on Collada model

Tags: three.js

I'm using [EdgesHelper](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Extras.Helpers/EdgesHelper) on a simple model that I exported from SketchUp. It is showing some diagonal lines like this:

[image]

How do I prevent those lines from appearing, so that the edges looks like what it appears in SketchUp? I tried setting the `thresholdAngle` but it doesn't help.

**Update:**

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/alan0xd7/6vLm5xsa/

This is the look I am trying to achieve:

[image]

Comment: Is your model a single mesh? Do you have interior faces? Can you provide a live link to a demo demonstrating the problem?

Comment: (1) You are rendering both the model and the edges helper in a scene without lights. Remove the model and you can see the helper clearly. All edges are rendered properly. (2) The reason for the extra edges is because you have two edges concurrent in your model -- a short edge and a long edge. You need to change your geometry. http://jsfiddle.net/6vLm5xsa/13/

Comment: And your animation loop is not required. http://jsfiddle.net/6vLm5xsa/14/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If you look at the first screenshot, how do I make my model render like how it appears in SketchUp, but with white lines and black surface? I am not very familiar with three.js, perhaps I'm not suppose to use the EdgesHelper for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are rendering both the model and the edges helper in a scene without lights. Remove the model and you can see the helper clearly. All edges are rendered properly.

The reason for the extra edges is because you have two edges concurrent in your model -- a short edge and a long edge. You need to change your geometry. This is not a problem with three.js

If you want to show the edges, but have hidden edges truly hidden, you need to make use of the webgl feature `polygonOffset`. You can use a pattern similar to the following:

```
var mesh = dae.children[0].children[0];
mesh.scale.set( 20, 20, 20 );

// replace the material
mesh.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {
    color: 0x000000,
    polygonOffset: true,
    polygonOffsetFactor: 1, // positive value pushes polygon further away
    polygonOffsetUnits: 1
} );
scene.add( mesh )

var helper = new THREE.EdgesHelper( mesh, 0xffffff );
helper.material.linewidth = 2;
scene.add( helper );
```

updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6vLm5xsa/15/

[image: fiddle rendering]

three.js r.71

Comment: I was able to remove the extra edge by manually editing the model's edges in Blender (doesn't seem it was possible to do in SketchUp).