# Best way to make a BufferGeometry contour in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'd like to make a specific **contour** in my **BufferGeometry**.  The goal is make a fill polygon and the lines around.

Now, I try using MultiMaterialObject, but the line **crosses** the square: http://jsfiddle.net/VsWb9/3918/

```
    var positionArray = [0,0,0, 0,100,0, 100,100,0, 
                         0,0,0, 100,100,0 ,100,0,0],
        colorArray = [];

    for(var i = positionArray.length;i--;)
        colorArray[i]=1 // white    


    bufferGeo.addAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(positionArray), 3));
    bufferGeo.addAttribute('color', new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(colorArray), 3));

    materialsArray = [
    new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors, side: THREE.DoubleSide}),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xff0000, wireframe: true, opacity: 0.2, transparent: true, shadding: THREE.SmoothShading})
        ];
    mesh = THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject(bufferGeo, materialsArray);
```

But I don't need the cross line. In this example, I use the square, but in my project there are thousands polygons (Pentagon,Hexagon, etc).
What is the best way to do the perfect contour, without the cross line?

- Make two separate "BufferGeometry" ? ( One using LineBasicMaterial with different sequence of vertices positions and other using MeshBasicMaterial with the actual sequence )
- Other?

Thanks

Comment: At link, click the mouse on black window to see a square.

Comment: Try `var helper = new THREE.EdgesHelper( mesh, 0x00ffff );`

Comment: Thank you!! Its worked, but i changed somethings:
`var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial(
        { vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors,side: THREE.DoubleSide }
    );`

Look the final example: [Result](http://jsfiddle.net/VsWb9/3922/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to highlight the edges of your geometry, you can use `EdgesHelper`:

```
var helper = new THREE.EdgesHelper( mesh, 0x00ffff );

helper.material.linewidth = 2; // optional

scene.add( helper )
```

If your mesh has another material, you may get z-fighting artifacts with `EdgesHelper`. A work-around involves `polygonOffset`. See [three.js EdgesHelper showing certain diagonal lines on Collada model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31226344/three-js-edgeshelper-showing-certain-diagonal-lines-on-collada-model/31232508#31232508). Also note its use in the updated fiddle below.

Your geometry has problems, however. Face winding order must be counter-clockwise. That is a separate issue.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VsWb9/3923/

three.js r.71

Comment: Thank you @WestLangley!! I didn't know about order counter clockwise for drawing faces. The final example: http://jsfiddle.net/VsWb9/3929/