# contour figure working with d3.js and Three.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, three.js

I'm carrying a GeoJSON :

(country.json -> https://github.com/johan/world.geo.json/blob/master/countries.geo.json)

with coordinates worldwide in a variable named data. I then apply a .mesh. I want to add the outline to the figures of the countries, that is putting a new THREE.Line, but not how. I get confused because I do not drive much d3.js then no how. thank you very much.

```
            var countries = [];
            var i, j;

            // convert to threejs meshes
            for (i = 0 ; i < data.features.length ; i++) {
                var geoFeature = data.features[i];
                var properties = geoFeature.properties;
                var feature = path(geoFeature);

                // we only need to convert it to a three.js path
                var mesh = transformSVGPathExposed(feature);

                // add to array
                for (j = 0 ; j < mesh.length ; j++) {
                      countries.push({"data": properties, "mesh": mesh[j]});
                }
            }

            // extrude paths and add color
            for (i = 0 ; i < countries.length ; i++) {

                // create material color based on average       
                var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
                    color: "#000000", 
                    opacity:0.5
                }); 
                console.log(mesh)       
                // extrude mesh
                var shape3d = countries[i].mesh.extrude({
                    amount: 1, 
                    bevelEnabled: false
                });

                // create a mesh based on material and extruded shape
                var toAdd = new THREE.Mesh(shape3d, material);

                //set name of mesh
                toAdd.name = countries[i].data.name;

                // rotate and position the elements
                toAdd.rotation.x = Math.PI/2;
                toAdd.translateX(-490);
                toAdd.translateZ(50);
                toAdd.translateY(20);

                // add to scene
                scene.add(toAdd);
            }
```

I have all the figures of the countries on the map, I put the outline, ie put a line above:
    http://postimg.org/image/3v9mc2jet/

I want the contour lines out as in Example (new three line ..):

http://postimg.org/image/qo5bqaon7/

Comment: Is `EdgesHelper` what you want? See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31484105/best-way-to-make-a-buffergeometry-contour-in-three-js/31494037#31494037).

Comment: @WestLangley no, I need the outline of the figure (new three line ..). Black lines outline color in each country as shown in the following image.http://postimg.org/image/qo5bqaon7/

Comment: @WestLangley in my code I want to know how I can add the coordinates to generate lines of each country (new THREE.Line ..)

Comment: Is each country a separate extruded shape? If yes, then `EdgesHelper` will do what you want. Try it.

Comment: @WestLangley yes they are separate extrude shapes but I need put the lines (new three line..) of each  country...how do?

Comment: Like I said, use `EdgesHelper( mesh )`. Or see http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_shapes.html and use `points = shape.createPointsGeometry()`and `line = new THREE.Line( points, material )`.

Comment: @WestLangley WITH edgeshelper lines also appear on the sides of the figure. . That's why I want to do with a "line" (new three.line). in the code I put how I can put lines above the figure? also in the example (see black lines http://postimg.org/image/qo5bqaon7/)

Comment: If you only want lines in front of the figure then use  `geo = shape.createPointsGeometry();  var line = new THREE.Line( geo, material ); line.position.set( x, y, z );` Add the line as a child of the extruded mesh. Also see http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_extrude_shapes2.html.

Comment: @WestLangley 
how to do it in my code?

Comment: @WestLangley i try..  var geo = toAdd.createPointsGeometry(); 
                    var line = new THREE.Line( geo, material ); 
                    
                    scene.add(line);

Comment: but not working in my code..appears "toAdd.createPointsGeometry is not a function"

Comment: @WestLangley Now if it works! thank you. materialSide var = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial ({color: "# FF0000"});
                     Countries geo = var [i] .mesh.createPointsGeometry ();
                     var line = new THREE.Line (geo, materialSide);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87101/discussion-between-user5115790-and-westlangley).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a `THREE.Shape`, and you want to create an outline, then the pattern to follow is like so:

```
var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, linewidth: 2 } );

var geometry = shape.createPointsGeometry();

var line = new THREE.Line( geometry, material );

line.position.set( x, y, z );

scene.add( line );
```

If you are rendering the shape and the outline, this may look better if you set `renderOrder` so the line is rendered last:

```
line.renderOrder = 2; // the default renderOrder for all objects is 0
```

In the current version of three.js, this will not work correctly if the shape has holes.

three.js r.71