# How to make visible edges that are intersects other objects' surfaces?(THREE.js)

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am working in a three.js project. In the project I have to show all edges of geometries even those edges are intersecting with other objects' surfaces.

Here is the snippet code that illustrates my problem.

```js
var camera, scene, renderer, material, stats, group, wireframeMaterial;
init();
animate();

function init() {
    // Renderer.
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true, alpha:true,clearAlpha:0,clearColor: 0xff0000});
    //renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    // Add renderer to page
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    // Create camera.
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
    camera.position.z = 400;

    // Create scene.
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
  group=new THREE.Group()

    // Create material
    material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();

  wireframeMaterial=new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0x000000, side:THREE.FrontSide ,transparent:false,opacity:1,linewidth: 1 })

    // Create cube and add to scene.
    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(200, 200, 200);
    var mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    group.add(mesh1);
    
        
    var geometry2 = new THREE.BoxGeometry(100,100,100);
    var mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry2, material);
    group.add(mesh2);
    mesh2.position.fromArray([0,150,0])

    
    
    var edges = new THREE.EdgesGeometry( geometry );
    var line = new THREE.LineSegments( edges, wireframeMaterial );
    mesh1.add( line );


    var edges2 = new THREE.EdgesGeometry( geometry2 );
    var line2 = new THREE.LineSegments( edges2, wireframeMaterial );
    mesh2.add( line2 );


     scene.add(group)

    // Add listener for window resize.
    window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    group.rotation.x += 0.005;
    group.rotation.y += 0.01; 
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function onWindowResize() {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}
```

```css
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/97/three.min.js"></script>
```

In fiddle code you can see there are two cubes top of each other. I want bottom edges of small cube to become visible. One solution is making mesh basic material transparent. However in that situation edges that are behind cubes it self will be visible too which is not allowed in the project.

So are there any alternative solution for this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a good solution, you need to use the `polygonOffset` parameters of the basic material.

```
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  polygonOffset: true,
  polygonOffsetFactor: 1, // positive value pushes polygon further away
  polygonOffsetUnits: 1
});
```

Found it on this question: [three.js EdgesHelper showing certain diagonal lines on Collada model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31226344/three-js-edgeshelper-showing-certain-diagonal-lines-on-collada-model)

EdgesGeometry will render the hard edges only.

WireframeGeometry will render all edges.

```js
var camera, scene, renderer, material, stats, group, wireframeMaterial;
init();
animate();

function init() {
    // Renderer.
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true, alpha:true,clearAlpha:0,clearColor: 0xff0000});
    //renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    // Add renderer to page
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    // Create camera.
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
    camera.position.z = 400;

    // Create scene.
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    group=new THREE.Group()

    // Create materials
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      polygonOffset: true,
      polygonOffsetFactor: 1, // positive value pushes polygon further away
      polygonOffsetUnits: 1
    });
    var wireframeMaterial= new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0x000000, linewidth: 2 } );

    // Create cube and add to scene.
    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(200, 200, 200);
    var edges = new THREE.EdgesGeometry(geometry);
    var line = new THREE.LineSegments( edges, wireframeMaterial );
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    group.add(mesh, line);
    
     
    var geometry2 = new THREE.BoxGeometry(100,100,100);
    var wire = new THREE.EdgesGeometry(geometry2);
    var line2 = new THREE.LineSegments( wire, wireframeMaterial );
    var mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry2, material);
    line2.position.fromArray([0,150,0]);
    mesh2.position.fromArray([0,150,0]);
    group.add(mesh2, line2);
    
  scene.add(group)

    // Add listener for window resize.
    window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);

    // Add stats to page.
    stats = new Stats();
    document.body.appendChild( stats.dom );
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    group.rotation.x += 0.005;
    group.rotation.y += 0.01; 
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    stats.update();
}

function onWindowResize() {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/stats.js/r17/build/stats.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I know. But I didn't get how that is related to my issue. I want to show only hard edges. The issue is when lines are intersects with other objects' surfaces, they vanishes. I want to prevent that.

Comment: Now I see the code was wrong somehow. It was earlier version of my script. I have updated it. Now you can understand my issue more clearly.

Comment: I've moved the small box one unit away from the big box and the line appeared. If you can do this in your project, then it's solved. If you can't use this (or don't want to) plz let me know so I can research a better solution.

Comment: sorry I am not allowed to do that :(

Comment: Thank you. It is a perfect solution.